# Spring boot OAuth2 SSO Cluster

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I was build SSO server with spring boot、Spring OAuth2. When in stand-alone mode，token was stored in memory, It runs perfectly. But now, **I want to run SSO server on multiple servers. I changed the store strategy with JDBC and then run two instances on port 9999 and 9998.** I don't know how to config the client and resources server of application.yml file. I tried the following configuration on client server:

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: mud
      client-secret: mud
      access-token-uri: http://localhost:9999/oauth/token,http://localhost:9998/oauth/token
      user-authorization-uri: http://localhost:9999/oauth/authorize,http://localhost:9998/oauth/authorize
      scope: read, write
    resource:
      token-info-uri: http://localhost:9999/oauth/check_token,http://localhost:9998/oauth/check_token
```

It not works... When I access the resource, SSO server redirect to 'http://localhost:9999/oauth/token,http://localhost:9998/oauth/token'.

**How to configure multiple SSO authentication server in spring?**

Answer (score 0):

I want to use zuul to fix this issue, I tried the following configuration on client server:

```
server:
  port: 8080
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:                                              
    client:
      client-id: mud
      client-secret: mud
      access-token-uri: http://localhost:8080/proxy/oauth/token
      user-authorization-uri: http://localhost:8080/proxy/oauth/authorize
      scope: read, write
    resource:
      token-info-uri: http://localhost:8080/proxy/oauth/check_token
  ignored: /proxy/oauth/token, /proxy/oauth/authorize, /proxy/oauth/check_token
zuul:
  routes:
    auth-server:
      path: /proxy/**
      serviceId: mud-microservice-security
mud-microservice-security:
  ribbon:
    NFLoadBalancerRuleClassName: com.netflix.loadbalancer.RoundRobinRule
```

When I access this client like 127.0.0.1:8080/env, it can be redirect to login page of SSO server. but when success to login, it not redirect to 127.0.0.1:8080/env and I access 127.0.0.1:8080/env again, it aways to redirect to login page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should config session share for your oauth instance

Comment: Can you better explain how this answers the question?

Comment: It seems that user log in the oauth2 instance1 but the following request is redirected to the oauth2 instance2. I assume that's why the login page shows again. Maybe share session between instance1 and instance2 should solve the problem.